# Django 3.0.7 - No Changes Detected after making Changes to Model

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am making changes to a model `AppContactCnt` to add new fields to handle deleting of records.
Here is that models.py

```
class AppContactCnt(models.Model):
    id_cnt = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # idcst_cnt = models.IntegerField()
    idcst_cnt = models.ForeignKey(AppCustomerCst, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idcst_cnt')
    idctp_cnt = models.ForeignKey(AppContactTypeCtp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idctp_cnt')
    idtrp_cnt = models.IntegerField()
    name_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    note_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    receives_emails_cnt = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    deleted_cnt = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    # date_deleted_cnt = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    # deleted_by_cnt = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_contact_cnt'
        app_label = 'easytrade20'
```

I tried to add in `managed = True` no change.

Also tried the following:
Delete all previous migration files and pycache files except init.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I am still getting `No changes detected`

I am not sure how to proceed, any assistance is apprecaited.

Comment: You actually didn't comment out the changes you made by using #, in code right?

Comment: @LetsSeo I didn't, the last 3 fields were new and added.  I was attempting to create a new change with the # to see if that would be recognized...  it was not.

Comment: can you add your `INSTALLED_APPS` ? @AlliDeacon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set **`app_label = 'easytrade20'`** in the meta option, but Django is unable to detect an app named **`easytrade20`** in your project. That's why there aren't any changes.

So, add **`easytrade20`** to your **`INSTALLED_APPS`** or remove **`app_label = 'easytrade20'`** from the model's Meta, and try again to run your migrations.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: @FelisEklof I did attempt that, and it still returned `No Change Detected`  Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The app is likely not listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` located in settings.py, therefore Django has not registered your application and will not detect migrations that need to be run in that application.

## Solution

Add `easytrade20` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and try again to run your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

If the answers above didn't work for you I propose you to make a model and migrations based on an existing database. The steps to complete this task are outlined below.

> Below I suggests that your app directory also called `easytrade20`.

> I think that you already have a database that you are working with and all migrations have been applied to it. If not, and saving the
> structure of migrations is not critical for you, then skip steps 2-3.

> If any of your other apps have migrations that depend on `easytrade20` migrations you need to repeat steps 2-5 for every of them (by renaming `easytrade20` to your app name) before starting step 6 (and 6+ steps are required for that apps too).

---

### 0. Backup your files and database before changes

### 1. Update your Django version to the latest release

`pip install django==3.0.* -U` for 3.0.X (`3.0.10` is latest release when I write these lines)

or

`pip install django==3.1.*` for latest one (3.1 have not so much differences from 3.0 and maybe it is right choice for you)

### 2. Check if all migrations are applied

Use [showmigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations) command to show applied migrations:

`python manage.py showmigrations`

You'll see structure with all apps and their migrations like this (`app1` and `app2` for example):

```
app1
 [X] 0001_initial
app2
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_some_other_migration
```

You'll see your apps and some django apps/third-party packages, like `admin`, `auth`, `database`, `sessions` etc.

If you'll see all `[X]` near every migration - all is fine, go on.

If you'll see some `[ ] migration_name` - try to apply these migrations first. Run `python manage.py migrate app_name migration_name` for every unapplied (unchecked) migration top down for every app (`app_name` for example).

### 3. Make new models based on your database structure

Use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) to generate models:

`python manage.py inspectdb > generated_models.py`

File `generated_models.py` will be created. You need to copy from this file all models that you created for `easytrade20` app. Replace your `models.py` with generated models and remove `managed = False` at least in the model `AppContactCnt`.

### 4. Remove information about `easytrade20` migrations from database

`python manage.py migrate --fake easytrade20 zero`

And now if you'll run `python manage.py showmigrations easytrade20` you'll see that all migrations unapplied.

### 5. Remove your migrations directory

That's it. Remove directory `easytrade20/migrations` completely.

Then if you'll run `python manage.py showmigrations easytrade20` you'll see text `(no migrations)`

### 6. Generate new migrations

Run [makemigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#makemigrations) command:

`python manage.py makemigrations easytrade20`

Folder `easytrade20/migrations` will be created. If not, then you'll need to check two things:

1. Your `settings.py` to ensure that `easytrade20` included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. Your `easytrade20` app settings. Ensure that your files have similar code:

```
# easytrade20/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'easytrade20.apps.EasyTradeConfig'
```

```
# easytrade20/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EasyTradeConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'easytrade20'
```

### 7. Apply initial migration

If you have database with this table then fake migration:

`python manage.py migrate easytrade20 --fake-initial`

If not, then run without `--fake-initial`:

`python manage.py migrate easytrade20`

### 8. Make changes to your model, create and apply migrations

Change your `models.py` file.

Run `python manage.py makemigrations easytrade20`. New file in your `easytrade20/migrations` directory will be created.

Run `python manage.py migrate easytrade20` to apply new migration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is registered inside the `settings.py`, and the `INSTALLED_APP` section.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is ever stumped by this, I had my models separated into different classes in a package `models`.  In the `__init__.py` of `models` I had to import the classes i.e.

`__init.py__`

```py
from app.model.Foo import *
from app.model.Bar import *
```

`app.model.Foo.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from app.models.Bar import Bar

class Foo:
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)
```

`app.model.Bar.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from app.models.Bar import Bar

class Bar:
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'

    text = models.TextField()
```